# Getting multiple IP addresses

Tags: macos, ip, lan

I was wanting to assign one computer all the possible ip addresses on a lan so I can kick everybody else off the network and so that nobody else could join. It also needs to be done on a macbook since its on my school network and my school computers a mac.

Comment: So basically you want to sabotage your school's network?

Answer (score 0):

Can only be done if you have access to the school router.